# Android DocumentsProvider from server storage

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, document-provider

how would I pull the directories from a web service rather than local assets?I need to write a DocumentsProvider that shares documents located on a server. I am at a total loss at how to do this. The server has an API that allows me to retrieve information about the documents and the libraries they are contained in.

For example - I can retrieve a JSON array from `http://myserver/api/getlibraries` which contains objects holding information about the document libraries available, like CreatedBy, Name and how many documents are in that library. I can also download the file from `http://myserver/api/getdocument?docID=<documentID>`

**How would I pull the directories from a web service rather than local assets?**

I can't give much more details as I don't know what details to give, but feel free to ask and I'll do my best to provide.

Thanks for any help

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#custom

Comment: @CommonsWare I've read through that and am still at a loss.

Comment: It would help if you would explain **specifically** what you do not understand. FWIW, [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/Provider) that implements a `DocumentProvider`, albeit one that pulls from assets rather than a Web service.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's what I'm struggling with, pulling from a web service.

Comment: @CommonsWare how would I pull the directories from a web service rather than local assets?

Comment: Talk to whoever wrote your Web service and ask them.